# Make hidden vc to vissible discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want when someone join a hidden voice channel in discord. then the member role get an update and normal member can see that lock vc .. and when user disconnect that vc then again normal member can't see that hidden vc

```
    let channel = "id"
    let roleid = "id"

    console.log('Event Triggered')
    if (oldMember.channelID === null && newMember.channelID !== null) {
        //Someone Joined
        console.log('someone Joined')
        let newUserChannel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.get(newMember.channelID)
        if (newUserChannel.id === channel) {
            newUserChannel.overwritePermissions([{ id: roleid, allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"] }]).then(changedChannel => {
                console.log(`Changed Permission of ${changedChannel.name}`)
            })
        }
    }

    if (newMember.channelID === null && oldMember.channelID !== null) {
        //Someone Left
        console.log('someone Left')
        let oldUserChannel =  oldMember.guild.channels.cache.get(oldMember.channelID)
        if (oldUserChannel.id === channel) {

            oldUserChannel.overwritePermissions([{ id: roleid, deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"] }]).then(changedChannel => {
                console.log(`Changed Permission of ${changedChannel.name}`)
            })
        }
    }


})


Function is not working why 
no error the connect event is not working
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide channels and allow people to see them once joined, this can be done with channel permissions, it doesn’t have to be a bot. Disallow viewing the channel, but allow speaking, so if they are moved into the channel they can still speak.

EDIT:
Check this for more information about overwritePermissions: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#replacing-overwrites